# Trying to convert string to datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, calendarextender

I am trying to restrict a user from entering a new record if the date requested already exits.   I was trying to do a count to see if the table that the record would be placed in already has that date 1  or not 0. I have a calendar extender attached to a text box which has the date.

I keep getting either a:

String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

or

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

depending on the different things I have tried.

Here is my code.

```
 TextBox startd = (TextBox)(DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox5"));
                TextBox endd = (TextBox)(DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox7"));
                DropDownList lvtype = (DropDownList)(DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList6"));

                DateTime scheduledDate = DateTime.ParseExact(startd.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
                DateTime endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(endd.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);

                DateTime newstartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(startd.Text);
                DateTime newendDate = Convert.ToDateTime(endd.Text);

                //foreach (DataRow row in sd.Tables[0].Rows)
                DateTime dt = newstartDate;

                while (dt <= newendDate)
                {
                    //for retreiving from table
                    Decimal sd = SelectCountDate(dt, lvtype.SelectedValue, countDate);

                    String ndt = Convert.ToDateTime(dt).ToShortDateString();

                    // //start = string.CompareOrdinal(scheduledDate, ndt);
                    // // end = string.CompareOrdinal(endDate, ndt);

                    //trying to make say when leavetpe is greater than count 1 then throw error. 
                    if (sd > 0)
                    {
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('Date Already Requested');</script>");
                    }
                    dt.AddDays(1);

                }
```

^^^
This version throws the: "String was not recognized as valid date type" error

But if i replace the string with either of these :

```
  /*-----------------------Original------------------------------------
                string scheduledDate = Convert.ToDateTime(endd).ToShortDateString();
                string endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(endd).ToShortDateString();
                -------------------------------------------------------------------*/

                /*----------10-30---------------------------------------
                DateTime scheduledDate = DateTime.Parse(startd.Text);
                DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse(endd.Text);
                ------------------------------------------------------*/
```

I get the "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to type 'System.IConvertible'." error.

I am just trying to stop a user from entering a record date that already exits.

```
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Height="19px"
                        Text='<%# Bind("lstdate",  "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>' Width="67px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="TextBox5_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True"
                        TargetControlID="TextBox5">
                    </asp:CalendarExtender>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="TextBox5" ErrorMessage="*Leave Date Required" 
                        ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <br />
                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator18" runat="server" 
                        ControlToCompare="TextBox7" ControlToValidate="TextBox5" 
                        ErrorMessage="Leave date cannot be after start date" ForeColor="Red" 
                        Operator="LessThanEqual" ToolTip="Must choose start date before end date"></asp:CompareValidator>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Would be helpful to see the actual string that is being passed when getting this exception.

Comment: I edited it to show the aspx code? The error stops me from even entering the page.

Comment: DateTime scheduledDate = DateTime.ParseExact(startd.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);

Comment: The "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to type 'System.IConvertible'" occurs when you try to parse the textbox itself instead of the textbox.Text.

Comment: Your parse format string `"dd/MM/yyyy"` does not match your bind format string `"{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"`. Are your sure the format the date is being entered in is correct given your parse specifier?

Comment: When exactly is this code executed? If it's executed when loading the page, the textboxes will be empty so you're trying to parse an aempty string.

Comment: preforming both changes on the aspx and code behind resulted in "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." on DateTime scheduledDate = DateTime.ParseExact(startd.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: what is the value of startd.Text, when you debug? is it empty?

Comment: startd has null value. scheduledDate with the parseExact has value of 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM

Comment: Then that's you problem. You can expect null value to be parsed as date. before doing DateTime.ParseExact, you should check for (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(startd.Text)). If startd (the textbox control) itself is null, then it means your DetailsView.FindControl is not working.

Comment: how simple, thank you!  (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(startd.Text)) worked @tranceporter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems that `startd.Text` is null, you should only do `DateTime.ParseExact` if the text is not empty or null. You can use:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(startd.Text))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check for (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(startd.Text))

via : tranceporter

Answer (score 0):

The `"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to type 'System.IConvertible'"` occurs when you try to parse the textbox itself instead of the textbox.Text.

When exactly is this code executed? If it's executed when loading the page, the textboxes will be empty so you're trying to parse an empty string, which is obviously to the correct format.

Comment: doing this threw an "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." error.